# Set UIImageView frame in initWithCoder

Tags: ios, uiimageview, storyboard, initwithcoder

I am trying to set the frame size of an UIImageView inside a subclass of UICollectionCell but it does not work. I use storyboard.

In the code, everything works but the last line regarding the imageView. 
If i put the code in drawRect it works ok.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
if ((self = [super initWithCoder:decoder]))
{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.85f alpha:1.0f];

    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 2.0f);
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;

    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because your imageView (I believe it's and IBOutlet) is not yet initialized, it's still nil. Be aware that some of you variables/properties are being initialized inside init's method. Set you breakpoint and you will see. Try set the imageView values somewhere else such as drawRect (as you suggest) or awakeFromNib.

Answer (score 0):

Is the image view being moved later by a different object? Try moving that code into layoutSubviews

Add this method:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
}
```

Comment: No it does not work in layoutSubviews. The view is not being moved later... I resolved the problem by calling the method in drawRect (not optimal, but it works)